# Using elastic search how to filter employees with more than 80% attendance in a date range

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic search I am trying to filter employees with more than 80% attendance in a given date range.

Model is 
{
  userId_ids:1,
  AvailableDays:["2019-05-10","2019-05-11","2019-05-12",......,"2019-12-30"]
}

availability days can be 5 year data and need to fetch all employees with more than 80% availablity in a date range "2019-01-01"- "2019-12-30"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with the below solution where I've made use of below noted aggregation queries. Note the tree structure of query which would help in understanding the parent/sibling aggregations.

[`Range Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)

- [`Terms Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

  - [`Cardinality Aggregation on date field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)
  - [`Top Hits Aggregation (to retrieve the document)`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)
  - [`Bucket Selector Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

Now I've simply made use of Range query first to filter the documents that would fall in that range.

For sake of simplicity, I've considered using the below query which would return the **list of employee whose attendance is greater than or equal to 80%** from **`1st-Jan-2019 to 10th-Jan-2019`** i.e. only for **10 days**.

Note that I've added some comments wherever required to change the query depending on your use-case

### Aggregation Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size": 0, 
   "query":{  
      "range": {
        "availabilityDates": {
          "gte": "2019-01-01",
          "lte": "2019-01-10"
        }
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "student":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"userId.keyword"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "count_dates_attendance":{  
               "cardinality":{  
                  "field":"availabilityDates"
               }
            },
            "hits": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10                          <---- Returns only 10 students. Change to see more students
              }
            },
            "myfinal":{  
               "bucket_selector":{  
                  "buckets_path":{  
                     "attendanceCount":"count_dates_attendance"
                  },
                  "script": { 
                    "params": {
                      "count_days": 10              <----- Change this to 365 if your range is for an entire year
                    }, 
                    "inline": "params.attendanceCount/params.count_days >= 0.8"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Only thing that would you need to do is manually calculate the number of days between two days and update the `count_days` based on your requirements. I've added 10 because that's the range I've used in my query.

Hope this helps!